# jQuery: select all `<td>` of a `<tr>` except a particular `<td>`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to select all `td` of the clicked `tr` except the `td` that has input check box. The following code allows me to not select the `td` that has input field:

```
$(".table-row td:not(:has(input))").click(function(){...}
```

But I couldn't access the value of the other `td`.

What cause the problem? How can I select all `td` except a particular `td`?

**.html**

```
<tr data-id="{{ test.id }}" class="table-row">
 <td class="form-check">
  <div class="form-check">
   <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input check-ele check-prevent" type="checkbox" value="">
    <span class="form-check-sign">
     <span class="check"></span>
    </span>
   </label>
  </div>
 </td>
 <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
 <td name="test_name">{{ test.test_name}}</td>
 <td name="test_type">{{ test.test_type}}</td>
 <td name="test_date">{{ test.test_date|date:"m/d/Y" }}</td>  
</tr>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".table-row td:not(:has(input))").click(function(){
  $('#editModal').modal('show');
  let row = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id');
  var test_name = $(this).find('td[ name="test_name" ]').text();
  console.log(typeof(test_name));
  // return empty test_name. The row I click on has test_name with value `Entrance Exam`
  var test_type = $(this).find('td[ name="test_type" ]').text();
  var test_date = $(this).find('td[ name="test_date" ]').text();
  var date = new Date(test_date);
  var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
  var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var test_date = date.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
  $('#edit_test_date').val(test_date);
  $("#edit_test_name").val(test_name);
  $("#edit_test_type").val(test_type);
```

Comment: Just do nothing if the `td` has an input element/has index 0/has class `.form-check`/...

Comment: _"But I couldn't access the value of the other td."_ well how were you attempting to get the value(s) of other tds? Note the js line you showed just sets a click handler, has nothing to do with accessing a td's content.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I've update my post in detail. please check it. Thank

Comment: Change `find()` to `siblings()` or use `find()` within the row element. You are looking for other `<td>` as children of `this` and that isn't what the structure is

Comment: as i see your code i think you have used `form-check` class only if it has input, so if im not wrong your selector would be `td:not(.form-check)`, isint this what you are looking for?

Comment: @charlietfl I change from find() to siblings() and It works! Thank a lot

Comment: @Manjunath It's not what I want to do. Thank for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selector is working fine, as you can see in the following example, but you are accessing the *values* of the other `<td>`s incorrectly. Here's another way to do it:

```js
const cells = $(".table-row td:not(:has(input))");

cells.click((e) => {
  const row = e.target.parentElement;
  const [ name, type, date ] = Array.from(row.children).slice(2).map(cell => cell.getAttribute('name'));
  
  console.log(`NAME = ${ name }, TYPE = ${ type }, DATE = ${ date }`)
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

td {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

td:not(:first-child) {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
}

td:not(:first-child):hover {
  background: yellow;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 44px !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="">
        </label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td name="counter1">Counter 1</td>
    <td name="name1">Name 1</td>
    <td name="type1">Type 1</td>
    <td name="date1">Date 1</td>  
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="">
        </label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td name="counter2">Counter 2</td>
    <td name="name2">Name 2</td>
    <td name="type2">Type 2</td>
    <td name="date2">Date 2</td>  
  </tr>
  
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>
      <div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="">
        </label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td name="counter3">Counter 3</td>
    <td name="name3">Name 3</td>
    <td name="type3">Type 3</td>
    <td name="date3">Date 3</td>  
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem in your code is here:

```
let row = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id');
var test_name = $(this).find('td[ name="test_name" ]').text();
```

You should be selecting the actual row (`<tr>`) instead of its `data-id` attribute, and then use that `row` to find the different cells and the value of their `name` attributes:

```
const row = $(this).closest('tr');
const test_name = row.find('td[name="name1"]').text();
```

Comment: I've updated my post in detail. I accessed the value of other `<td>` incorrectly.

Comment: @Sokunthaneth Please, take a look at the updated answer. In short, you need to call `.find()` on the `<tr>`.